# mod_rewrite not working with escaped slashes

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

mod_rewrite ReWriteRule seems to have an odd issue correctly interpreting a URL when it contains an escaped forward slash.

```
RewriteRule article/([^/]*)/? articles/article.php?id=$1
```

http://www.domain.com/article/1303960/test/.html - This works and redirects correctly

http://www.domain.com/article/1303960/test%2F.html - This gets ignored by mod_rewrite and gives a 404.

I tried adding [NE] to the ReWriteRule to no avail. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is intended Apache httpd behavior.

In Apache httpd 2.0.46 or later you can use [AllowEncodedSlashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) directive (in server or virtual-host config) to allow use of %2F in path info section of URL.